# Are political avatars and profiles OK?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, profile-page, offensive, profile-picture

Are political profiles and/or avatars appropriate? Should they be allowed?

Some context: Today I've had a chat with this user:

[image: User profile page containing Free Palestine flag]

I'd like to hear what the community thinks about this.

*Full disclosure*: I am an Israeli from the "other side", our chat was pleasant and on a positive note, we discussed several things some related to JavaScript and some related to politics and philosophy in the JavaScript chat room. The discussion on both subjects was polite and high quality.

Personally I don't mind the avatar one bit, and the only thing that might be problematic here in my opinion is the unrelated discussion it might cause. Another user (anonymously) told me it bothers them, so I figured I'd bring it to discussion here. The link to the user profile is omitted to prevent irrelevant voting backlash and/or otherwise so common in meta.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you would not make this discussion about the user (and make them easy to find) but rather about the topic of political avatars. I fully understand that it's well within your right to choose not to honor my request.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: sure, removed the remark.

Comment: I'm also giving a _"religious"_ statement with my avatar, and state some of my philosophical viewpoints in my profile. I don't see anything wrong about doing so.

Comment: I think this user is obviously trying to piss people off with his avatar and name combination. However I wouldn't usually see any problem with what us Americans would regard as "patriotism" as long as it isn't directly insulting.

Comment: I think I've seen a related [meta.se] question about impersonating people...here it is: [Is it ok to impersonate a public figure?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13039/163250).

Comment: I don't have any issues with the avatar or politically/religiously  focused avatars, i just disagree with the idea of impersonating a public figure *and* attaching it to a politically or religiously focused avatar. Whether we should do anything about it, probably not, other than in derogatory cases, but the user shouldn't be surprised when someone reacts negatively to it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Your avatar is not taking a strong stance on an active and highly controversial war.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh! There are actual and highly controversial wars ongoing [about these positions](http://freetibet.org/). These are just not hyped currently, and tend to be _forgotten_ by the media.

Comment: @Jhawins _" I wouldn't usually see any problem with what **us Americans** would regard ..."_ :O= ...

Comment: Appropriateness aside, it seems dumb to promote causes which *could* irritate others.  They might have the answer you need and be disinclined to answer as a result of the av.  The more radical type could hurt him with question DVs to the point of a ban.

Comment: @Plutonix The only reason these things can be irritating is because we give them the power to *be* irritating by assigning significance to them through discussions such as this. We already have the means to protect against one user consistently down-voting another, and it's the asker's loss if they choose to not read an answer because their political opinion gets in the way (and yet, nobody would choose to ignore an answer because the answerer's avatar or user name is a character from a cartoon they don't like... why is that?)

Comment: @Jhawins Us Americans also wish that political discussions were on topic in comments so that we could gently inform you of our opinion of your implication that "us Americans" are the global authoritative source on what "patriotism" is regarded as.

Comment: For clarity I wasn't saying Obama is patriotism. I was saying voicing his opinion, with the avatar that states "Palestine will be free" is patriotism for ones own country.

Comment: @JasonC which of course, is my point *we cant control how others will take it* nor what they will do about it.  I dare say *more than one* could be put off political/religious/moral/etc/etc avs

Comment: @JasonC I provided positive input for this discussion. I am an American, therefore identifying myself as an American in this way is correct. There are no implications here of racism, culturalism or a phat ego as an American. Do not clutter this with your assumptions. I said nothing justifiably offensive and did not put myself, or America on a pedestal of any kind. Culture clearly applies for this discussion so I identified myself in a neutral way.

Comment: @Plutonix What you say is totally valid; but I maintain that as a group we *can* control how others will take it. We are complete products of our surrounding culture and environment, and in your context you and I are the "surrounding culture and environment" of said "others". If everybody around you tells you something is potentially offensive, then it *is* potentially offensive.

Comment: @JasonC I am flagging a comment as off-topic as you are steering this into some weird irrelevant direction for no reason. All of this needs removed except for the relevant comments. Don't try to turn this into something other than a question about the appropriateness of political/cultural avatars.

Comment: @Jhawins My conversation with Plutonix is independent of my comments towards you and is directly on topic. My conversation with you we should probably flag and delete.

Comment: Of course this guy lives on the moon.  Of course.

Comment: @Jhawins: I don't understand why you felt the need to point out that the avatar is patriotic. We know it's patriotic. And what does American patriotism have to do with it? You may be American but we're not. Your comment seemed to indicate that you think not understanding patriotism for countries other than the US is commonplace here which, in itself, is somewhat offensive because most of us aren't even _from_ the US. In short, it's your Americentric assumptions of your target audience that riles people up. Thanks.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Heck, it riles me, a native USA citizen, up as well. Not to mention that the use of the "American" demonym in a global (online) context is [fairly USA-centric](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/155766/55308) in itself. So many bad things in between the lines there. Then we end up wondering why we get dirty looks when we travel.

Comment: @JasonC: Yeah you guys get a bad rep and deserve most of it :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *fist shake*

Comment: @JasonC: BTW for the record I'm rather fond of the demonym "USAian".

Comment: This guy would not have had this much exposure (actually almost none) if you wouldn't have posted this question here. But apart from that, I don't see this avatar as offensive, and a political statement in itself should be allowed. After all, an avatar is an image of you, and if you feel strongly about politics then it make sense to reflect that in your avatar.

Comment: As long as _red lines_ are preserved, there should be no reason to disallow/ban political avatars. I'm Palestinian, my avatar and profile says so; I don't use this place for political discussion, there are plenty of places outside SO.

Comment: Why don't we just keep the site about programming and everything else out of it?

Comment: btw, let the "_Another user (anonymously) told me it bothers them_" speak out for themselves, why does it bother them? What's so _offensive_ about it? What part of the avatar bothers them?

Comment: @Omar some people do not want to participate in meta discussion. I can ask but I can't force someone to talk. I think what I hoped to accomplish was accomplished well. There is now a clear consensus that political avatars are OK and not offensive as long as they're positive. I think the community's overwhelming support helped a lot and I got the benefit of showing that an Israeli (me) can speak up for my Palestinian friend and that we're having a sane and constructive discussion about all this (so no one says "but Israelis would get offended etc", those people do _not_ speak for us).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum +1000 For you last statement. Way to show people not everyone has to believe or feel what others think they do.

Comment: Heh. I used a rainbow-coloured atheist "A" logo as my avatar on Christianity SE for a while.

Comment: I completely agree with you, this is annoying you saw the same thing happening with linked in, from a career site goes to a political discussion and second twitter, completely annoyed and unfortunately you cannot block a user here either.

Answer (score 212, accepted):

My take on it is that if the avatar is not directly insulting or attacking another, it's not for us to moderate. In the example above, it is advocating something positive for a particular group of people. I understand that there is an implied criticism of another group in this, but as long as someone is not explicitly being called out, I don't think it is our place to step in and force a change.

However, I and others have had to force changes for other avatars that we felt were inappropriate. Bloodied Star of Davids, Calvin urinating on the Star of David, and boots grinding the Star of David into the ground are not appropriate avatars for this site. Those are explicit attacks on a particular group of people, and do not belong in public avatars here.

There is a fine line between what is and is not appropriate, and each case would need to be examined on its own merits, but my general take is that politically motivated avatars in support of a cause are fine, but ones that attempt to attack others are not.

Comment: This answer (and the other one too) represents my view point too. I think that as long that they are about a positive cause (empowering a people) and not a negative one they're perfectly fine.

Comment: My fine line is "has this become a huge distraction?"  It deflates any arguments about "well, this is offensive in my culture, even if it is not in yours," etc.

Comment: While I find this motivation well-based, I wonder if it's appropriate to convey **any** message using an avatar, signature, choice of words etc. that doesn't has with the site's purpose to do. There's a gray area and there will always be people trying to speak their mind on unrelated subjects (e.g. politics on SO) but should we deem that OK just because the content is positive? Besides, I'll bet that there are a lot of folks who'd take offence of this particular avatar. Only the fact that **someone** raised the question on the subjects means to me that the avatar isn't neutral enough.

Comment: @KonradViltersten See the answer by the user in question. While it can be a dicey topic- The user is showing cultural support _for their culture/heritage_ and restricting that is completely and utterly wrong. Yes, some people may not like it, but at the same time it would be bad to censor pride in one's heritage.

Comment: @Kendra I agree with you that **we** should never, ever, ever censor other people's right to expression. I believe that the dude (or dudess) themselves should censor that, in certain situations. I'm glad that the user is proud of his heritage. I dislike (slightly) the fact that he makes me aware of that. I don't want to be aware of their gender, race, location, beauty, possession, family constellation, sexual preference etc. I'm not going to impose on anybody what to do, of course. I just wish that people were as neutral as I am. Try to conclude anything about me based on my 2+ years here. ;)

Comment: @KonradViltersten you appear to be white, male, 37, Swedish, living in Stockholm - all of which you've put on your profile, along with a picture of you.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: I can conclude, in about 5 seconds, that you're white, male, and Swedish.  It's a bit hypocritical to claim that you "wish that people were as neutral as [you were]" when you're not really very neutral in your profile at all – you make us aware of your gender, race, location, and physical appearance, to borrow the first part of your list above.  (And there's nothing wrong with that!)  It's just that showing anything about where *you're* from/who *you* are happens to be immediately uncontroversial, which is not the case for lots of other people.

Comment: @Blorgbeard 38, not 37 but that's beside the point. I stand corrected and gladly admit that I expressed myself too sloppy. Mount. Insert. Foot.   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten: For what it's worth, I think the reason your suggested rule overreaches, is that we would *never* consider it worth the time to enforce. If someone has an avatar that expresses the opinion Snoopy is cool, it's not worth the moderators' time to fix. So IMO it would be hypocritical to make the rule "all avatars must be to do with the site's purpose", but then only enforce that rule on political subjects and not on Snoopy :-)

Comment: @AntalS-Z As Blorgy pointed out, there's a glitch between my expressed statement and the actual view. My bad totally. What I meant was, of course, exposure of opinions that **are choices**, that are **relevant** to this forum and that are accessible **without** the receivers explicit **decision**. (I.e. being a male isn't a choice, preferring Java to C# is relevant and what's on the profile requires someone to actually follow a link.) Having said that, I'd like to stress once again that I needed to refine the statement that I've made and I appreciate that others took time to point that out.

Comment: @SteveJessop I agree fully. And once again - I don't say we should restrict the avatars and such. It should be allowed to use anything one wishes. I'm saying that just because one **can** and is **allowed** to do that, one **doesn't have to** exercise that right. If, for some reason, it turns out that Snoopy is a controversial subject, the user should be considerate enough to just change the cause of controversy. (NB: They shouldn't be forced to do so. They should have politeness and courtesy to make that choice themselves.) If someone would remark on my avatar, I'd just change it not argue it

Comment: @KonradViltersten: the moment you have a photo as your avatar, you are conveying implicit messages. You are posing for a photo on what looks like an office, wearing a tie. You appear to be comfortable in the corporate world. You are also implicitly identifying yourself as belonging to a specific race and gender. If you didn't want to convey all that information, you could just use the default gravatar. While it's been said that _in the Internet, everyone's a dog_, that is less and less true with people exposing their photos, friend lists and everything else on the Internet.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: well, since you mention "remarks", your avatar *is* kind of blurry at that resolution ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop It's going to sound like something I've come up with just now but the bluriness **is** intentional so that people can't conclude the gender nor race. It was my aim all along, you know. Just like I stated that everybody should do! (Disclaimer: I **have indeed** come up with it just now. The blur is due to a sucky web camera. But it would sure be nice to have considered that in advance, hehe.)

Comment: @ninjalj Yupp. As I said before - I'll have to stand corrected. I do convey some details of me that I haven't been aware of. Having admitted to being wrong (which I have no problems with, once that's been proven) I'd still argue that there's a difference between exposing one's gender/race/occupation etc. (one can see these IRL by looking at me) and political views, religious beliefs and sexual preferences (which, usually, don't show). I think I'm opposed to **intentional demonstration** as opposed to **implicit information leakage**. One doesn't need to put effort into **hiding** personal...

Comment: @ninjalj ...information. If it shows, it shows. But we don't have to put effort into **demonstrating** it neither. You could tell by my tie that I'm white collar. So be it. But if I'd went to any lengths to **demonstrate** that I'm well-dressed at work, that'd be less appropriate of me. I'm not saying we should restrict the freedom of expression. I'm just saying that **having a right** to express oneself doesn't imply the **necessity** of exercising that right. And if it happens, well... so be it. No big deal.  :)

Comment: it does offend if there's a clenched fist in it!

Comment: @BerryTsakala In this case it's open to interpretation. Not everything is what you may think.

Comment: How about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/users/895245/ciro-santilli-%E5%85%AD%E5%9B%9B%E4%BA%8B%E4%BB%B6-%E6%B3%95%E8%BD%AE%E5%8A%9F "My goals: make the Great Firewall of China GFW block Stack Overflow pages where I have posted, in order to make Chinese programmers mad ... talk to me ...
less efficient and work less well..." @tim-post

Comment: @Randel - Stack Exchange evaluated that account and found nothing offensive or abusive about it. You can discuss this with SE employees, but I don't see their profile as demeaning another group of people. Criticizing a particular government, yes, but not attacking Chinese citizens themselves.

Comment: @BradLarson: To be honest, I came here exactly because of that particular profile, which irks me to no end. While it may be not demeaning "to a particular group of people" (I'm not sure about this either), it's certainly *inflammatory* and, I'd say, spammy and trollish/disruptive (as in "deliberately creating noise in every thread it appears on for no particularly useful reason"). I believe that it's not reasonable and that if it targeted some other organization or government (say, *for example*, the US of A) reactions would be different. I'd really like not to see that kind of stuff on SO

Comment: **Moderator note:** Comments are not here for political fist-fights. Take it to chat. When you are there, try to find common ground and show the rest of the world you are humans with understanding and compassion.

Answer (score 48):

I think the following:

- they are allowed
- they are not formally discouraged

I also think the following:

- they should be allowed
- they should be formally discouraged

As for whether πάντα's avatar is also inflammatory because it has "religious" overtones, no, of course not. We can safely apply that thing called *common sense* here. The avatar in the OP takes a strong political stance on an active, controversial and highly polarising military conflict with many civilian casualties involved. Emotion relating to this event is likely to be quite strong, wouldn't you say? It's best not to make the situation worse by spreading it onto SO. I dunno, go on a march, or something.

Comment: IMHO the problem lies in the criteria for formal discouragement. Is the problem in the nickname? The raised fist imagery? The political slogan? All of the above? In that case, wouldn't religious signs such as what πάντα ῥεῖ refers to be discouraged too?

Answer (score 39):

Our [terms of service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) <sup>(Section 4 - Restrictions)</sup> on this are quite clear:

> Under no circumstances will Subscriber use the Network or the Service to (a) send unsolicited e-mails, bulk mail, spam or other materials to users of the Network or any other individual, (b) harass, threaten, stalk or abuse any person or party, including other users of the Network, (c) create a false identity or to impersonate another person, or (d) knowingly post any false, inaccurate or incomplete material.

I can think of no *reasonable* person that would believe Barack Obama would be on a site for programmers while showing solidarity for Palestine. Obvious parody is obvious, and I see no reason to  intervene *unless*:

- The person doing it is intentionally creating a disruption (which is a whole other issue)
- The parody itself is creating a disruption (please, don't impersonate Hitler, nobody likes that)
- The person is otherwise not following the rules of the site (also a whole other issue)

If it appears that someone *is* trying to pass themselves off as someone else in an attempt to harass or defame them, then we've got sections C and D kicking in, possibly B - and once you get past two letters we're probably done talking anyway.

As for the avatar? I don't see anything beyond a peaceful show of solidarity and support. It's not attacking, demeaning or slandering anyone. If anything, I'd rather start in on the people that have yellow in their avatars because I *really, really hate yellow*.

In all seriousness, I see no intent to make anyone feel uncomfortable or unwelcome by using the avatar that the user chose. *That's* really where the difference lies, and perceived intent can sometimes be really tricky business. Fortunately, this time, it's pretty clear.

Comment: Note to self: Yellow is bad choice in case of the avatar wars :) I'd rather have mods on my side.

Comment: Why ur so racist Tim?!

Comment: My avatar is yellow `:(` _Note to self: Beware of Tim!!_

Comment: I'm made a small edit that I think clarifies your second point. It was not readily apparent to me that you meant this, and that interpretation only occurred to me after several days of thinking on it. If that is not in line with your intent, please edit for clarity.

Comment: @jpmc26 Presumably *actually* being Hitler is also discouraged.

Comment: The reference to the terms of service is quite out of date, so you might want to update it. The "restrictions" are now in section 6, and the quoted text itself doesn't appear to be in that document. I'd edit this answer myself, but I don't actually know where that text got moved, or if it's even being used any longer.

Answer (score 17):

It doesn't bother me; and my take on this is that this person can put their opinion in their avatar / name the same way I can put a screenshot from my favorite game in mine - also an opinion.

Arbitrarily (essentially) disallowing opinion-based avatars simply because the topic is politics instead of, e.g. anime, only furthers a cultural trend towards being overly-sensitive and thinking everything is offensive, because it sets such things apart and *defines* them as significant.

The same goes for names. I can choose the name of my favorite cartoon character or celebrity without raising an eyebrow. Disallowing political figures' names simply because they are *political* figures is similarly arbitrary and also serves only to define an otherwise nonexistent significance of making such a choice.

The fact that there's a meta post about it at all means that at least *some* effect was made, and only enforces the use of this sort of thing as a way to have an impact. Not only should they be not disallowed, they should not even be acknowledged as special, and this meta post should be deleted.

The only thing that *should* be actively discouraged / disallowed are political discussions in post comments (since they are unrelated) and in chat rooms where they may be off topic - and that goes for anything unrelated / off-topic, political or not.

Additionally, actively impersonating somebody should of course be disallowed, and that goes for impersonating *any* figure, political or not.

Mild rant: Note that we are judging such users to be more / less likely to discuss politics than anybody else simply because of their politically-themed avatar (i.e. we don't assume somebody with a cartoon character in their avatar is consumed only by that cartoon and wants to discuss it endlessly - we shouldn't do the same for a political image either).

Comment: While your answer is well worded... This meta doesn't cover _just_ the avatar. The name is covered as well. So, out of curiousity, what would your opinion be on using the name of a political figure (assuming the user does not actually share a name with the US President which we will not be able to prove) as their nickname for the site?

Comment: @Kendra Applies equally to the name as well as long as they are not actively impersonating, which applies to any figure, political or not.

Comment: Fair enough. At the same time, I do think the meta should stay- It's highly unlikely that this situation will never arise again. In fact, it most probably will and having this here will be helpful in that matter.

Comment: @Kendra I acknowledge that my own stance on the continued existence of this post may be harsher than most.

Comment: I think you're yet to realize the importance of bringing such topics into discussion here. It's through discussing things and voting on them as a community that we establish the etiquette that guides the site. Not talking about something doesn't make it go away. The fact of matter is someone _did_ tell me it bothered them (in confidence) means that this _is_ an issue and the best way to deal with it imo is to bring it to the community's attention. Making such decisions as a community is a strength of SE, not a weakness, discussing it as a community and deciding we allow it makes us strong.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum In certain cases not talking about something *does* make it go away; but this conversation is admittedly way late in the game for that, and that's the aspect of my opinion that I will concede. Nearly every moral value and reaction you have is a learned behavior from what was socially acceptable / questionable around you - made real *entirely* because it was talked about and acted on, except perhaps for instinctual responses to e.g. danger / pleasure.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I believe one point I am making that you *may* be missing can be made clear if you reflect on this question: Why aren't we having this exact same discussion about food / TV / movie / etc. based opinion choices in avatars and nick names? And I mean the *real* why, not just "Because we're not as sensitive about entertainment opinions." It's rhetorical; and too long and complicated to discuss here, but just take some time to think about it.

Comment: Probably because there isn't an on-going war with over 1500 casualties and 50000 rockets/shells about food / TV / movie etc, I guess that's what bothered some people. I promise I'll think about it more though. For what it's worth - it being OK was obvious to me (which I also clarify in the question itself), but I don't think it was clear to the people who complained about it to me so it was likely not clear to the whole community. Even here - there is some debate about it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum That's still not a real why. You can still go deeper into human nature and social behavior than that. I acknowledge that this isn't a popular thing to say and neither my internal feelings nor my intent are callous on the matter, and I am by no means attempting to downplay important beliefs and world events or draw comparisons, but saying "The reason this sensitivity exists is because sensitivity on a larger scale - resulting in violence - also exists" is rather circular. Why would there never be such violence surrounding food / TV / movies?

Comment: @Benjamin: If people cared as much about food / TV / movies as they do about national self-determination, then those things would be political issues. A "say no to FCC censorship" icon would be political and TV. Someone might say it disturbs them because they don't what their kids exposed to certain things. That's what politics (in part) *is*, a process for dealing with irreconcilable desires. So food is rarely political. If the community were to come out against political icons (which doesn't look likely), it would be a rule that you can't reference anything important enough to bother anyone.

Comment: @SteveJessop Try to argue with some vegetarians or vegans if food is rarely political. ;-)

Comment: @BlackJack: heh, well I meant more rarely than national sovereignty.

Answer (score 11):

"Are political profiles and/or avatars appropriate? Should they be allowed?"

Of course. Why on Earth would they not be? If you're offended, don't look. We all have brains and free will. Look away or choose to ignore it. You're an adult (hopefully). We're adults (hopefully)... or at least responsible and mature enough to represent them.

Besides, they're such a tiny piece of the full content on a page. They're insignificant. People are far too easily "offended" over nonsense issues these days, although I'm not accusing you of being offended.

One of the answers here said it's okay as long as it's "empowering a group," which is ridiculous to say the least. That's completely subjective and situational. It's basically saying it's okay as long as you attach feel-good emotions to it. In most situations, "empowering" one group, automatically belittles or is simply *against* another. What if someone was empowering a feminist group, KKK, or Zionists? Those groups are effectively against other groups. The other term someone brought up was "hate," as if that isn't 100% subjective. What one person might find hateful, another might find just and noble.

I think that the world has far too many offended individuals these days, I don't think we need it here too. Children and adults apparently aren't taught anymore that not everyone agrees with your opinion as to what's "empowering" or "hateful."

Live and let live.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide usernames and profile pictures with [uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en) filters. For example, if you find people named "Benjamin" offensive (sorry Benjamin), you can do this:

```
! Asker/editor name
stackoverflow.com##.user-details > a:has-text(/benjamin/i)
! Asker/editor profile picture
stackoverflow.com##.user-details > a:has-text(/benjamin/i):upward(2) > .user-gravatar16
stackoverflow.com##.user-details > a:has-text(/benjamin/i):upward(2) > .user-gravatar32
stackoverflow.com##.user-details > a:has-text(/benjamin/i):upward(2) > .user-gravatar64
! Padding between asker/editor profile picture and their username/points
stackoverflow.com##.user-details > a:has-text(/benjamin/i):upward(1):style(margin-left:0px!important)
! Comments
stackoverflow.com##.comment-user:has-text(/benjamin/i)
! main "Top Questions" page
stackoverflow.com##.s-user-card--link > .flex--item:has-text(/benjamin/i)
```

Now your question looks like this:

[image]

If you want to do it Stack Exchange-network-wide, just add the rest of the domains:

```
stackoverflow.com,stackexchange.com,askubuntu.com,stackapps.com,mathoverflow.net,superuser.com,serverfault.com##.user-details > a:has-text(/benjamin/i)
! and so on
```