# 1 week+ since joining and I still have the default LGBT flag as chat avatar

Tags: support, bug, chat, profile-picture

I joined 1 week+ ago and come regularly to chat room.

The problem is that my avatar in chat has never been changed from a LGBT flag despite having had a different avatar since joining, and the LGBT flag can be seen as offensive or rude to many people who have nothing to do with it.

Nonetheless people with this avatar won't receive *neutral* opinions or engage in a *neutral* discussion because they might be either be taken as **troll**, **not serious users** or just **someone who hasn't the same opinions as them**. While in fact 99% of time the user doesn't associate with such an avatar.

This is also an issue that attacks the core of the system which is **neutrality**.

The flag avatar I'm talking about:

[image: the flag avatar]

My avatar since joining is this though:

[image: normal avatar]

What's going on with this avatar? I've heard complaints from other users as well.

In a discussion we had it seems that it's related to accounts registering behind proxies and the likes, which is bad considered that many people register behind public WiFi or school's computers/internet as I did.

Is this a bug? If yes can it be fixed? If not, can you at least block this behaviour for people behind public WiFi or school's computers/internet?

Comment: That looks like a bug but I think I speak for the whole chat when I say we're perfectly fine with the LGBT flag as an avatar. If you feel a user discriminated you or abused you based on that avatar let a moderator know and that user will be dealt with.

Comment: Personally, I am flag-blind. I wouldn't have guessed what it stood for -- and even now you told me, my reaction is "meh".

Comment: Shouldn't the default avatar an [identicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon)? I think the flag avatar has/had something to do with troll users setting offensive avatars.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum You're absolutely right in that matter. What I'm talking about is that such a decision goes against a user's neutrality and will. The user most likely doesn't want to be associated with something he isn't or maybe he wants to stay **neutral** by having an identicon instead, for example.

Comment: Related [on the topic of 'controversial' avatars](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267368/are-political-avatars-and-profiles-ok). I agree that this looks like a bug and of course you should be able to change your icon to whatever but a user most definitely shouldn't feel intimidated because of their preferences here.

Comment: There's an actual duplicate of this -- about the rainbow flag specifically -- somewhere, but I can't find it. Might be on Meta.SE.

Comment: Let me get this straight - you put in a random e-mail address? Why did you do this?

Comment: @ChrisF Because I don't trust permanent email providers anymore, this for reasons that would be off-topic explaining in the comments and SO in general.

Comment: @AdamBarak - at least choose your *own* throwaway e-mail address rather than using somebody else's. If we have to send you a mod message it will get sent to the e-mail address you provide. We can't know that it's not really your address so there's a real risk we'll inadvertently reveal some personal information to a random person. Do you really want that?

Comment: I will take this tip and act accordingly, thank you. But if I get sent a mod message doesn't it end up in the notification inbox instead?

Comment: Why did you choose glasses?

Comment: @AdamBarak - Mod messages always get sent to your SE inbox, but are **also** sent to the e-mail you provide just in case you don't visit the site for a while.

Comment: @ChrisF Ok thank you, I'll look for a private email provider that is good for me.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Because of reasons.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You are using YOPmail as your email account.

We recently had a very nasty troll hijack chat with *really offensive images*; the troll accounts were created via TOR exit nodes to circumvent IP blocks, and used YOPmail as the required email account to automate signup.

Even though their accounts had only 1 reputation point, they then joined many chatrooms as often as they could to bombard everyone with the offensive avatar images.

To thwart their abuse, all accounts with YOPmail accounts now get assigned a default chat avatar instead; the fact that the rainbow flag has been used here is not entirely a coincidence. Think of it as troll trolling.

The work-around is simple. Don't use a YOPmail temporary email address on your account.

This measure may also be in place for other troll-specific markers; other temporary email providers may also be listed for this treatment.

Comment: That's definitely nasty. But why would they choose to do something so time expensive and not ludicrous? What do you suggest I do? Make a new account without using yopmail and ask for deletion of this one?

Comment: Why not just change your email associated with this account?

Comment: @AdamBarak: simply change the email address on your account to a real address? Your email address is *private*, visible only to you and to moderators. We could only see it because you created a screenshot of your account.

Comment: @AdamBarak: as for the troll's motivations: this particular individual is in desperate need of serious mental health assistance. There is a long history of trolling and mental illness there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I can see it, there's no other motivation. I will now research for a better email provider that's also private. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Hey wait a minute. Using this particular flag (with its association) is "..not entirely a coincidence. Think of it as troll trolling." Now *that* is not okay in my book.

Comment: Yeah, really. I don't get it. Where is that decision discussed, Martijn? Or do I need to post a new question about it? You don't "troll" people with the LGBT flag.

Comment: @CodyGray if it was discussed at all it was among the community managers and developers, and the measure is likely temporary and aimed at one very specific troll.

Comment: I don't think that's good enough, Martijn. It doesn't make hatred and bigotry acceptable just because it's aimed at one very specific person.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not making any value judgements here, all I did was report on the why and wherefor. That said, I don't see hatred or bigotry at play here.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus - It was not intended as an insult. Their original avatar was a swastika, so it was changed to something much more positive, something that stood for pretty much the exact opposite of what they had for an avatar. It was intended to defuse a troll by replacing a negative with a positive, not to insult them with it.

Comment: Not everyone sees overt minority activism as a good thing for equality.

Comment: Next time, use puppies. No one will complain.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Puppies??? You meant kittens!!!

Comment: @tchrist: !! How dare you objectify animal children and abuse them as political instruments!!