# Is there anything to do with users with a profile picture clearly endorsing violent acts?

Tags: discussion

I have encountered a user recently, with a profile picture depicting a person appearing to throw a stone using a [sling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sling_(weapon)) in front of a [palestinian flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Palestine).

I find that this is clear endorsement of violence ([against Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israeli%E2%80%93Palestinian_conflict), though I don't think it is particularly important here). I assume it wouldn't be ok for example to use an [ISIS flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jihadist_flag#ISIS_variant) as profile picture.

Am I being unreasonable to say this, & if not, is there anything to do with given user?

Comment: flag any of his posts with a custom flag and explain your concern

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243388/175248

Comment: Thanks for both comments. Why the downvote?

Comment: You're going to get people who want to pore over the definition of "clearly" and "endorsing" (and maybe even "violent"), so I would strongly recommend that you take this matter out of the Court of Public Opinion and flag down a moderator (follow the link I sent you to get a good bead on where to start).

Comment: Alright, thanks! Saved your link. Since I have pointed to this post in the explanation of my  flag, I think it might be not a good idea to delete this immediately, I'll wait a while until a moderator looked at it & then delete this post if poring over definitions start.

Comment: Given that I have linked this post in my flag explanation, do you think it is ok to leave it here for a while?

Comment: That user came up in meta before, they were wondering why they got so many mystifying downvotes on their helpful posts.  Now deleted.  No lack of canonicals for "I vote because I hate", like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267368/are-political-avatars-and-profiles-ok/267467#267467).

Comment: isn't the slingshot and the palastanian flag, not a sign of resistance?

Comment: slingshot and Palestinian flag is sign of resistance against oppression. so don't cry zabop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think you need to report the person, Just click on the flag and choose "in need of moderator intervention" then explain it to moderator.