# Is changing my profile picture to a Muhammad caricature allowed?

Tags: discussion, profile-picture

I know about this question: *[Are political avatars and profiles OK?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267368/are-political-avatars-and-profiles-ok)*

The [accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267370/8565438) says:

> There is a fine line between what is and is not appropriate, and each
> case would need to be examined on its own merits, but my general take
> is that politically motivated avatars in support of a cause are fine,
> but ones that attempt to attack others are not.

Is a Muhammad caricature considered as attacking a cause (i.e., Islam), or is it, in the light of recent events, a sign of support for free speech and the general values of the French Republic?

---

**Update:**

Following moderators' request not to put them into a situation where they need to decide this issue, I won't do it.

Comment: I would prefer that you didn't.  We have enough problems with political issues on this platform already.  There are plenty of other places on the Internet where you can promote your political causes.

Comment: I wouldn't particularly care, I wouldn't consider it an attack against Islam nor would I care about your political views

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah :/ I'm not deeply involved with any of those, my biggest "reach" is SO.

Comment: Your best face for Stack Overflow is to use it for what it's intended: to help other people with their programming problems, irrespective of their political ideologies or yours.

Comment: I don't intend not to help those who disagree with me, or anything like that.

Comment: I don't get why this post is downvoted though, why is this not a legitimate question.

Comment: Even if it was, the second question should be whether you _should_. Do you really want to go after a group with almost two billion followers, most of which would never, ever imagine causing others harm? by all means, show support for the attack, but showing support by effectively targeting an entire religion isn't the way to do it.

Comment: Downvotes on meta often express disagreement over the question's premise.

Comment: By doing this, you essentially put the onus on the site moderators to decide whether the conduct is offensive, alienating, and/or causing a distraction. As Robert mentioned, we'd rather not be in the position of making that decision when it comes to political issues, so please don't put us into that position.

Comment: @CodyGray Of interest to me, why was my original comment deleted? I understand if the ones after that would be controversial, but why my original comment?

Comment: Meh.. who cares?  I think that Islam, a massive, organized religion, can shrug off such wastes of server space:)

Comment: @10Rep Uh, the one where you replied to gnat? I deleted that because I deleted gnat's comment linking to a largely-irrelevant historical event, and I don't generally leave replies when I delete the comment to which the reply is directed. Do also note the irony of leaving *more* comments to discuss comments that were deleted to keep the comments section from getting too noisy...

Answer (score 7):

From the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct):

> We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion — and those are just a few examples.

Whether something is an intentional attack is not the standard used here. If it's likely to offend or alienate, then don't do it.

Comment: The COC is kind of clashing within itself. On one hand this answer says it doesn't matter if it is an intentional attack or not, but then the COC says assume good faith. Which to believe?

Comment: *...but then the COC says assume good faith.* @10Rep That phrase does not appear in the Code of Conduct. But I think you're also conflating how the Code of Conduct talks about content on the site versus the people using the site.

Comment: yes, you are right that the COC doens't say that anywhere (I think it should). This case in itself is different. It will offend people no matter the intent. I like the point you made in the answer, and I think you should include the fact that many people may not assume good faith in a matter like this.

Comment: I think there are already a lot of avatars that offend someone or some group. It's very difficult to never offend anyone. Is an avatar of a flag offensive if the flag is of a nation that is occupying your country? I'm not sure that we should be so quick to say no to this.

Comment: @10Rep [We need “assume good intent” back in the Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335026/313443)

Comment: @Scratte Are you familiar with the profile picture the OP intends to put? A country flag isn't offensive to a group because your saying, "I am part of this country". The profile picture the OP intends to put is completely different, and refers to a historical event. it's as if I put a blue american flag as my profile picture. That will offend a huge group of people. But if I put the indian flag, I am just saying I am indian. Also, one more thing, this particular caricature is offensive because of specific rules in the Islamic religion.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I see... I am familiar with the old COC then.

Comment: @10Rep I think there are people that will say that the rules of the religion is debatable and only some argue that it's against the rules. Also.. I remember 10 different images as caricature, not just one. So I cannot possibly know which one they mean to use.

Comment: Interjecting here to request that any debate over **whether** something is offensive or **why** be taken to a chat room for discussion so that the inevitable back and forth isn't flooding my notifications. (Also, any disagreement with the Code of Conduct itself should be made into a separate feature request asking for changes.) This isn't particularly a complaint about your last comment 10 Rep (since you'll get a notification for this one) but I can see the fight coming and I don't want to get pinged about it.

Comment: @BSMP perfectly understandable. I don't think this debate is even supposed to be discussed here. I would rather it not, and I'm sure many people think the same. For that reason I have deleted the last comment.

Comment: @10Rep 'But if I put the indian flag, I am just saying I am indian' no!  You are obviously supporting India over the issue of Kashmir sovereignty!  I am offended! ( not really, just making the point that some will take offence over anything:)

Comment: @MartinJames that is true. People will take offense at pretty much everything, no? Especially at something like this, which is why I said no.